# What is the diffraction pattern of the single slit experiment with the circular cylindrical observing screen centered at the slit?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

> $\textbf{Question}$ What is the diffraction pattern of the single slit experiment if the observing screen is replaced by a circular cylindrical screen so that the central line of the cylinder contains the slit?

My guess is that the diffraction pattern may look connected, whereas the pattern looked disconnected with the planar screen.

I'm just starting to study physics as a hobby. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [HyperPhysics derivation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html#c1) the angular position $\theta$ of the m$^{\rm th}$ minimum for a single slit diffraction pattern of width $a$ is given by $a\sin \theta = m \lambda$ where$\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light.

Suppose that the first minimum occurred at $10^\circ$ then the positions of the minima on a flat screen and a cylindrical screen would look like this:

[image]

I have exaggerated the angles to show an effect whereas in practice as per the HyperPhysics derivation the angles are all less than $5^\circ$.

So for small angles there is very little difference between what is seen on the two types of screen but for larger angles you can see that the linear spacing of the minima on a flat screen increases much more rapidly than for the cylindrical screen.